# Return multiple values without using an array formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to use an Excel formula to lookup multiple values, but I'm not able to use `INDEX` or `SMALL`, rendering most array-formula solutions unfortunately unusable.

An example scenario is below:

1 sheet contains 2 columns.
Column A contains non-unique cells
Column B contains unique cells
In column C, I need to return all cells from B where the adjacent cell in Column A contains the character "A".

[image]

How can I do this without using array formulas?

Comment: Can you use ***OFFSET()*** and ***MAX()*** ??

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Is using a filter an option?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that uses neither **INDEX()** nor **SMALL()** nor array formulas.

With some data in **A1** through **B20**:

[image]

In **C1** enter:

```
=IF(A1="A",1,"")
```

and in **C2** enter:

```
=IF(A2="A",MAX($C$1:C1)+1,"")
```

and copy down.  Finally in **D1** enter:

```
=IF(ROWS($1:1)>MAX(C:C),"",OFFSET($B$1,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),C:C)-1,0))
```

and copy down:

[image]

This technique uses column **C** to mark the "good" rows in such a way that its easy get get any data from them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve your desired result with just formulas as you are trying to dynamically fill Column C. You can do it manually by filtering your values and deleting the rows that don't contain "A" in Column A. Otherwise I suggest to create a little VBA script that loops over the array `A:B`.